# Error: Failed to list functions for project

Tags: firebase-hosting

[can anyone help in **firebase hosting** after all configuration below error is occuring](https://i.stack.imgur.com/efCIC.png)

Answer (score 0):

Downgrading the firebase-tools version to 11.13.0 will solve it
Answer is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73978504/3235512